# Modifier or Add-on to make mesh more square

Tags: mesh, remesh

Is there a modifier or Add-on that makes non square mesh more square? I have this mesh that is somewhat square-ish but not quite. I have a dark memory in the back of my mind that I've seen a video in which a modifier or an Add-on was used to make mesh square again. But I cant find it anymore. Does anyone know if such a method exists?

[image]

EDIT: added image of model with disabled subdivision modifier

[image]

Comment: How does your mesh looks like with disabled Subdiv modifier?

Comment: @vklidu See edit

Comment: Try *Smooth* modifier (works in the same way as *Smooth Vertex* operator or *Relax* in *Mesh Tool* addon.